# Login facebook rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estoy desarrollando una app en Rails que estara integrada con facebook al inicio de sesión, pero al ir testeando el codigo me arroja el siguiente error.
`uninitialized constant Users`
Estoy usando Devise y omniauth-facebook

devise.rb

```
config.omniauth :facebook, "App ID", "App Secret", callback_url: "http://localhost:3000/users/auth/facebook/callback"
```

model/User.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
   # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
   # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
   :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :omniauthable, 
   omniauth_providers: %i[facebook]
end
```

routes.rb

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: 'users/omniauth_callbacks' }
root 'main#home'
```

Estoy usando rails en su ultima versión y ruby `2.5.1`

Comment: Agrega a tu pregunta el stacktrace completo de donde te arroja `uninitialized constant Users`, ahí debe salir la línea donde estás llamando a `Users` y no `User` como debería ser.

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer no tienes generados los controllers para la ruta intenta con el siguiente comando:

```
rails generate devise:controllers users
```